# Minimum of 2 nullable numbers

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code:

```
val num1: Int? = someObject.number
val num2: Int? = anotherObject?.anotherNumber
val numToFallBack = 2

val result: Int
if(number1 != null && number2 != null) {
   result = minOf(number1, number2)
}
else {
   result = number1?:number2?:numToFallBack
}
```

Basically I would like to end up with a number that is either the smaller of `num1` and `num2` taking into account that either or both could be `null`. In the case that both are `null` use a default value.
This code snippet above I think is too java verbose. How could I code this in a more Kotlin way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `when` statement,

```
val result = when {
    number1 != null && number2 != null -> min(number1, number2)
    number1 != null -> number1
    number2 != null -> number2
    else -> numToFallBack
}
```

Edit: if we want to choose the non-zero number, we can do this

```
val result = when {
    number1 != null && number2 != null -> when {
        number1 == 0 -> number2
        number2 == 0 -> number1
        else -> min(number1, number2)
    }
    number1 != null -> number1
    number2 != null -> number2
    else -> numToFallBack
}
```

Edit 2: if we do not want zero at all

Option 1

```
number1 = if (number1 == 0) null else number1
number2 = if (number2 == 0) null else number2

val result = when {
    number1 != null && number2 != null -> min(number1, number2)
    number1 != null -> number1
    number2 != null -> number2
    else -> numToFallBack
}
```

Option 2:

```
val result = when {
    number1 != null && number2 != null -> when {
        number1 == 0 && number2 != 0 -> number2
        number2 == 0 && number1 != 0 -> number1
        number1 == 0 && number2 == 0 -> numToFallBAck
        else -> min(number1, number2)
    }
    number1 != null && number1 != 0 -> number1
    number2 != null && number2 != 0 -> number2
    else -> numToFallBack
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to also take into account `0` besides `null`? I mean if it is `0` also I would want the other if `non null`

Comment: I'm not clear on your statement, if any number is zero, what is the expectation?

Comment: If the number is zero then the other number is the result unless the other is null and then it should be the `numToFallBack`

Comment: In your edit if the `number1 != null -> number1` that could still be 0

Comment: In that line we know number2 is already null, otherwise we would have gone through the 1st clause in the `when`.

Comment: Yes `number2` is null but if `number1` is 0 (i.e. non null) it should be set to `numToFallBack` not 0. If I understand the code snippet it sets to 0?

Comment: Your original snippet does not handle zero in any way.

Comment: Yeah that is true my post is buggy as it does not take 0 into account either. I realized it after I posted

Comment: @Francesc In your first version where zero is accepted, you can collapse your last three branches of the when statement by chaining Elvis operators.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the collections operators to get the min value of a group of nullable  numbers

```
listOfNotNull(num1, num2).minOrNull() ?: numToFallBack
```

if you only want to take non-zero numbers as requested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60979335/minimum-of-2-nullable-numbers/68313021#comment107884197_60979418)  comment, you can do this:

```
listOfNotNull(num1, num2).filter { it != 0 }.minOrNull() ?: numToFallBack
```